# An object 'pubsub' of type LightningComponentBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: pubsublwc

I am trying to deploy an application to my developer organization. The Github repo of the application and the command I am using are as below.

Github Repo:
https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes.git

Command to deploy: (Running from cloned location)
sfdx force:source:deploy -p "force-app" --targetusername "myorg" --loglevel INFO --ignorewarnings --verbose

The application was deployed fine when I did initially but later it started failing. I weirdly observed 1 difference in successful and failed deployments that there were 189 components deployed in successful deployments whereas there were 190 components in failed deployments. I do not know where this extra component came from.

Failed Deployment
[image]

Successful Deployment
[image]

Currently all the deployments are failing with the below error when I try to deploy with the above command;
Component Error:
An object 'pubsub' of type LightningComponentBundle was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

In order to resolve it, I found many solutions available on the internet talks about updating package.xml whereas there is no package.xml available in the application I am trying to deploy.

As I am newbee to the SF, please let me know the reason behind this error and how can I resolve it.

Folders
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what changes have been made between the initial successful deployment and the later failed deployments?

Comment: @AdityaNaag I didn't make any change in between successful and failed deployments.

Comment: I just took a fresh clone of the recipes repo, and followed the steps in Readme, and I didnt face this issue., which is why I'm curios why it failed.

Comment: As said above, it also worked for me initially. However are you aware wen do we get such errors. That way we may explore further...

Comment: Yep, typically when a meta file for a component is present, but the actual file is missing, you run into this error. Can you put a screenshot of your folder structure so that I can see if there is a stray file somewhere?

Comment: @AdityaNaag I have uploaded my code here https://github.com/AshwaniPratap8/my-lwc-recipe.git
Please have a look and let me know if you find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the `pubsub` folder from the `force-app/main/default/lwc` folder and it should work.

I will internally raise and investigate the issue. When I am using the SFDX command `sfdx force:source:deploy`, I am not seeing any issues because the `pubsub` folder is excluded in `.forceignore`. But when I try to use the VS Code extension to deploy, I am getting the exact same error as you are.

Comment: Thanks Aditya! It worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue when running the sfdx command `sfdx force:source:deploy` today. I was able to resolve it by removing the trailing slash and stars from the pubsub entry in .forceignore.